# How to let Ubuntu 20.04 virt-manager allocate volume space later

Tags: 20.04, virt-manager

In virt-manager, I open the "Connection Details" dialog and create new volume in the "Storage" pane. Although "Allocate entire volume now" is not selected, but the created volume files have the specified size instead of something much smaller. The file size is checked by:

```
sudo ls -l /var/lib/libvirt/images/
```

Why are the files have the full size? To make it easy, I only try to create 1GB and 2GB volume instead of something real.

Answer (score 0):

It's already done. Ubuntu use sparse file to store disk image.

```
ls -ls /var/lib/libvirt/images/vol.qcow2
```

shows that its norminal size is 1074135040 and it occupy 324 blocks

```
du --block-size=1 /var/lib/libvirt/images/vol.qcow2
```

shows that it occupy 331776 bytes which means block size is 1024 bytes